# Unable to increase size of "Macintosh HD" partition because recovery partition is at the end of it

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

I've been using Boot Camp with Windows 7 from almost the day I bought my MacBook Air in 2012. Recently, I noticed that I had a lot more free space in Windows than I needed so I shrunk it using Windows' built-in tools, intending to allocate that extra space to Mavericks.

I've been trying to expand my primary OSX partition and disk utility allows me to increase the size, but then when I press 'apply', a few messages show up above the button as if it is performing the change successfully, but then the partition layout diagram 'jumps' back to the original position.

I verified and repaired the disk (in recovery mode) due to inconsistencies but that still hasn't changed the behavior of disk utility.

I've also looked at the list of partitions from the command line, it it appears that the recovery partition is at the start of the free space, which the GUI app doesn't show at all. I assume Boot Camp moved every OSX related partition to be before Windows'. Here's the output of diskutil list:

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            70.0 GB    disk0s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
4:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD 2          19.9 GB    disk0s6
5:       Microsoft Basic Data Windows                 30.5 GB    disk0s4
```

So now I'm under the assumption that the resize is failing because of the recovery partition. Is there a way to move or copy the partition, or is there another way to reclaim the space as part of the main startup partition?

I forgot to mention that `Macintosh HD 2` (19.9GB) is the empty space that I want to merge with `Macintosh HD`. Diskutil won't show an entry for unformatted space as far as I could tell.